# find no of rows for text break lines in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyphenator

Is there any way to find the number of lines for the text break with `word-break:break-all` css property. Like suppose I given one div as

```
<div>Sample text to verify how many lines the text got broken</div>
```

And css is

```
div{
  width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

And now the browser will display like below and I want to know how many lines it got broken from the text.

Please help me how to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: So for the example you have mentioned, what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @void: I will add dynamically hyphen symbol with position absolute dynamically. If 3 lines then three hyphens with different positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the line height and any other styles affecting the height, you could check the [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) of the paragraph. After getting the height, subtract anything that is from the CSS then divide by your line height.

Disclaimer: I’m typing this from my phone and have not tested.

Comment: I checked in console for sample if it's 5 lines , I am getting Offset Height/line Height coming as 4.7 something. I hope It will work. Means Always output is total line number minus some points. So I will handle with your suggestion. I will let you know very soon. Thanks,

Comment: @Rayudu, yeah, [this is as close as I got for the moment](https://jsfiddle.net/v0tjrb0g/1/).

Answer (score 3):

You could calculate the size of the container against the line height:

```
var getLines = function ($container) {
    var linehight = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle($container[0], null).getPropertyValue("line-height"), 10);
    var boxHeight = $container.height();
    var numberOfLines = Math.round(boxHeight / linehight);
    return numberOfLines;
};

//To use it just call the function and pass in your class/selector
var numberOfLines = getLines($('.my-container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hyphens at the word break you can use `hyphens` css.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
div {
  max-width: 150px;
  hyphens: auto;
  margin:auto;
}

p {
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Now in some circumstances, designers may use squares and rectangles to help you visualize what should and could be in a specific location.</p>
</div>
```

But this solution has some browser support issue.

I found a helpful article for this **[CSS `hyphens`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/)**